# Bipedal haptic robot warriors - can they stand up and walk?

Tags: science-based, warfare, robots

Currently (2020) there are bipedal robots that can walk. However they contain a lot of expensive electronics in order to support their self-contained AI.

In crude (and heartless) terms, it's less expensive to lose an actual soldier than one of these machines.

What I am looking for is a purely haptic robot warrior, especially with respect to balance.

The human operator remains in a nearby bunker, wearing a haptic suit. The inputs to the human are strictly limited to essentials (clearly we don't want to transmit pain or injury back to the operator). The outputs to the robot are unfiltered and precisely match the movements of the operator.

The operator is immersed in a safe virtual reality while the robot actually fights.

There must be some electronic components but the requirement is tiny compared to those of AI.

The problem I have is the non-AI method of keeping the robot balanced. The human must "feel" the unbalance and then correct by bodily movements. This would be fine on a flat surface (probably), but the robot is traversing  rough terrain whilst the operator is ensconced in the bunker.

**Question**

How, if at all, can I overcome the problem of balance without using AI?

---

Note: The warrior looks convincingly human in appearance and size. This is partly to unnerve the enemy when it appears impervious to bullet wounds to the head etc.

Comment: This seems kind of a waste. The general assumption is that when robot warfare replaces humans, it's not going to be with android models, partly because how difficult it is to walk on two feet.

Comment: @Halfthawed - Thanks for the comment. However 99% of the suggestions on this site go against general assumptions!

Comment: The fundamental problem with all remotely operated vehicles is that they are susceptible to jamming and other counter measures.  They may require air/satellite links to provide over-the-horizon and non-line-of-sight comms and these can also be interfered with.  An army fully dependent on these would require considerable effort just to maintain a comms network with redundancy (in case part of it is destroyed or interfered with), security and protecting the comms assets.  What action does a remote vehicle take when it has no comm link ?  The odd drone is one thing, but an entire army like this ?

Comment: @StephenG - Yes. I wasn't thinking of an entire army. Some roles are more dangerous than others. For instance the robot could be a scout, or the leader of a charge to test the strength of the enemy before commiting humans.

Comment: *"Yhey contain a lot of expensive electronics:"* because they are **prototypes**. Once the engineering details are worked out and the devices are moved to mass production the costs will go down, down, down. Look what happened to the prices of autopilots for quadricopters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Frame Challenge - The AI Isn't Important

The expensive part of making a humanoid robot isn't the tech inside them helping them walk (computers and gyroscopes are cheap) but the actuators and power supplies.  You're taking probably the least expensive (in production terms) bit out of the robot.

A tremendous amount of *development* money is spent coming up with the processes that allow them to walk, but the challenge isn't supporting the AI, it's all batteries and actuators - and providing the AI with the kind of feedback you'd need to provide your haptic operator anyway.

So while you could conceivably have a teleoperated robot (though latency would probably be unacceptable for balance purposes), it doesn't solve the problem you seem to be trying to solve.

Comment: Hmm ... good argument.